# Prevent container reuse on AWS Lambda or shard by caller

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sandbox

I'm using AWS Lambda to let users execute arbitrary code, with all of the associated risks. Since lambdas are throttled and time-limited, the primary risk in my view is poisoning the environment for future calls in the event of container reuse.

Is there a way to detect, prevent or shard container reuse on AWS Lambda by caller without redeploying a function?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was asked before and unfortunately, the answer is "No". You have no control over the underlying "framework". You can read a bit more about that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, this still doesn't seem to be supported (see [this blogpost](https://pfisterer.dev/posts/aws-lambda-container-reuse/) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/issues/354)). What you can do instead is kill any leftover processes from the previous invocation and delete the contents of the `/tmp` directory.